# c++ password handling security practices?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, passwords

I am creating a c++ class that handles a username and password.

I was trying to do some research on some rudimentary, but effective practices for me to handle this information, in c++, so it can't be easily found by someone, for example, scanning memory and variables to determine the information.

By rudimentary, I mean something that would not take a lot of work; I don't want to program an entire cryptography library, random addressing system, or even a hashing function.

Also, i'm assuming it would be better to not even maintain this information in a variable, and get rid of it as soon as I do not need it?

Edit:

No, I would not be saving this information to disk, only keeping it in variables in memory.

Edit2:

The class is platform independent and uses boost.

Edit3:

here is the declaration for the function:

```
void authenticate(const std::string & user, const std::string & pass);
```

Comment: Are you storing to disk? If so, please plan to put some effort into hashing+salting. If it's in memory only, it's less of a big deal on most platforms since you need admin/debugger permissions to access another processes' memory. If this is windows, you could use bcrypt.h to access secure hashes.

Comment: If you are not going to store your password securely (in other words, use a hash of some sort), then you may just as well store them in clear-text. Just make sure you inform any users of your system that this is the case, so they have a choice to not use the product.

Comment: @VoidStar see my edits; no I would not be storing this information to disk, only memory. Also, the class is platform-independent and uses boost.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Right now the function that retrieves this user and password just takes them as const string &, wouldn't that already expose the information? What would be the alternative? Hashing wouldn't take place until after these variables are initialized with the username and pass?

Comment: Then, I'd assume that the password is as safe as the general system - in other words, if someone "outside" has access to it, then the password is not safe. If it's a "secure" machine, then password is safe. If someone KNOWS how your software works, they can break in the "handle password" function, and look at the password.

Comment: What do you authenticate against?

Comment: @MatsPetersson it's an https post request to open a tcp connection with the provided user and pass.

Comment: and you send the password over the net in clear or via ssl/tls  ?

Comment: @Christophe yes, the password is in clear, however since it's https, the connection is encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No rudimentary technique will protect a password from someone who has a debuger and can access the memory !

The safest way is therefore not to store the password, but only a hash of it. There are many implementations available as for example [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6234) open source one from a trusted source.

And yes, erase your variable when you no longer need it.  I.E:  OVERWRITE the value, not just destroy the variable (and if you want to be really on the safe side, you'd write random values on it, but that's overkill here):

If it's a string, it's worth mentionning VoidStars advice:

```
 string pwd; 
 ....
 std::fill_n(&pwd[0], pwd.capacity()-1, 0xff);  // really overwrite
```

Comment: Note that if the password is in a `std::string`, you need to overwrite the values using `password[0]=0`,  `password[1]=0`, etc. until the length of the string. Setting `password=""` simply frees the old string on most platforms, but the password could exist for a while in the unused heap. However I don't see any value in overwriting with random values.

Comment: Right now the function that retrieves this user and password just takes them as const string &, wouldn't that already expose the information? What would be the alternative? Hashing wouldn't take place until after these variables are initialized with the username and pass within the function?

Comment: That's the whole problem:  as soon as you have a password in clear you are vulnerable.  Calling your function with a const, means that you have no opportunity to clear the password in your authenticate function.

Comment: There is a problem with clearing keys or passwords in memory when you don't need it: compiler will likely optimize it out. 
[1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74280/would-it-be-good-secure-programming-practice-to-overwrite-a-sensitive-variable)
[2](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-class/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/protect-secrets.html)
[3](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/MSC06-CPP.+Be+aware+of+compiler+optimization+when+dealing+with+sensitive+data)

Comment: @MaciejS Excellent remark (and very good links about this topic).  So yes, make the password variable `volatile`.  The C++ stantard then consider access to these variables as side effet, which makes sure it's not optimized away.